# ObjectAnimator does not animate

Tags: java, android, animation

Hey I am working on a simple android app where I want to use some animation.
I have tried to use the ObjectAnimator like this :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

        final ObjectAnimator animator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(button, View.ROTATION, 180);
        animator.setDuration(1000);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                animator.start();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

But the ObjectAnimator just sets the value. Thus the button is directly reversed.

I hope anyone knows what to do.
Thanks.

Comment: you have disabled animations in `"Developer Options"`

Comment: Thanks to pskink. I don't know how many hours I searched for a solution and I would never have guessed this. Thanks.

Comment: sure, your welcome

Comment: Lol, and  I though my app was broken xD Thanks for this answer!